# Communication between two different pages using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket, socket.io

How can I communicate between page A.html and page B.html using socket.io? Using different ports perhaps?

Comment: For a single user viewing the two pages simultaneously?

Comment: No, user A is viewing A.html and user B is viewing B.html from different machines. I'm trying to figure out how to get them to communicate with each other.

Comment: Have you read up on their website ( https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ ) ?  Because what you are asking is overly broad and not a specific question.

Comment: The chat demo is single page that gets updated for everyone using it. I'm trying to communicate between two different pages (different HTML).

Comment: You understand that it doesn't matter if it is one page or different pages, right?  So long as they connect to the same place it doesn't matter. ( https://socket.io/docs/client-api/ )  The `io()` can take in a url.

Comment: PageA.html connects to your server with socket.io, PageB.html connects to your server with socket.io.  PageA can then send a message to the server and when the server receives the message (depending upon what the message is), it can decide what to do with it such as send it to the PageB connection.  Everything goes through the server with socket.io.  The server decides what to send to whom.  I'd suggest you look at the chat example on the socket.io website as it's one example.